# Rename [two-step-authentication] to [two-step-verification]

Tags: discussion, tags

Apple IDs can be protected by

- the feature [two-step verification](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204152) (legacy), currently tagged [two-step-authentication](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-step-authentication),
- the feature [two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915), currently tagged [two-factor-authentication](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-factor-authentication).

Since the name of the legacy feature is ‘verification’ not ‘authentication’, I propose the tag for the legacy feature is renamed to reflect the correct name of this feature, [two-step-verification](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-step-verification).

Comment: Your grey tags are confusing to me. TSV matches STA in the first bullet. TFA/TFA match on the second bullet. Lastly you say TSV in the end - shouldn’t that be TSA?

Comment: @bmike The grey tags are confusing due to the discrepancy between the name of the feature and the tag name on this site. I’ve attempted to clarify, hope the edit makes more sense?

Comment: Proposal as written makes sense to me!

Answer (score -3):

Apple calls this Two-Factor Authentication for all new sign up and all OS inclusive of iOS9 and El-Capitan or newer.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201303

We need to keep that as the main tag. I would argue we merge two step verification into TFA and have only one tag. Please vote for this if you want this exact merge to happen. Other options (reversing the merge or keeping these separate - please post an answer to cover that option.

- One tag of [two-factor-authentication](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-factor-authentication)

Comment: I disagree with this since the two features are distinct. The separation of the tags is what lead to the correct answer given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345925/how-to-recover-apple-account-login-when-2-step-authentication-without-apple-devi) vs an incorrect answer which would have been given with the incorrect tag.

Comment: I agree that the two are so similar and could remain unified, but conflating one with the other isn't a good thing.

Comment: I vote for the merge of both tags as Apple is *automatically* [migrating accounts from two-step verify to two-factor auth](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207198).

Comment: @Allan ‘*…when you sign in to iOS 11 or later or macOS High Sierra or later*’, so for a family member with an iPad 2 and iPhone 3G that's never happening! Verification and authentication are distinct functionality and a possible migration path from Apple's implementation of one to the other does not mean the tags should be conflated imo.

Comment: @grg I think we should have an answer here explaining why the tags should not be combined - confusion over which process to follow would be increased clearly so I’d like to upvote a “no - we don’t want this to be merged or linked or made synonyms”

Comment: We're talking about two products, one obsolete and another about to become "vintage" in less than a month with a service Apple is bound to kill off shortly thereafter.....if not now, in very short order, this will be a moot point.